# Local repo doesn't work on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: package-management, 21.04

When creating a package from multiple .deb files using `dpkg-scanpackages` it works on all systems except 21.04 which gives an error when trying to do `sudo apt --allow-insecure-repositories update` saying that the "Packages" file is missing.

On all the other systems this file is created automatically, and placed into `/var/lib/apt/lists/_home_username_path_to_the_repo` but on 21.04 that file is a symlink to the "Packages" file in `/home/username/path/to/the/repo` so I guess it expects it to already be created but `dpkg-scanpackages` doesn't make one, so what's the proper steps to create on 21.04?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, basically what was confusing me was that when creating "Packages" file, I had to zip it up, because the older systems unzip it and copy it into `/var/lib/apt/lists` during `apt update`, but 21.04 creates a symlink instead so "Packages" just needs to not be zipped, so it is actually simpler, but different from before so I got a bit confused.